# Custom ToString Extension not working - VB.NET

Tags: .net, extension-methods, tostring

I have the following code

```
Module StringExtensions

<Extension()>
Public Function ToString(ByVal e As Elements) As String
    Return e(0).ToString()
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function ToString(ByVal e As List(Of Element)) As String
    e.ToString("|")
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function ToString(ByVal e As List(Of Element), ByVal delim As String = "|") As String
    Dim s As String = ""
    For Each e1 As Element In e
        s = String.Join(delim, s, IIf(e1.Terminal, "!", "") & e1.Name)
    Next e1
    Return s.TrimStart(delim).TrimEnd(delim)
End Function

End Module

Class Elements
Inherits List(Of Element)
'...Various properties and methods
End Class
Class Element
'...Various Properties and methods
End Class
```

### My Question:

For some reason only the ToString extension with the delim variable can be called.
VS2010 wont even show that there are any other ones.
I have tried having only one of the two ToString's with no variable inputs

Why is this?

I am using a similar setup with a different class and this works fine.
As far as I know I haven't done anything wrong syntax wise.

Comment: Pick a name, any name, just not ToString.

Answer (score 3):

Every class in .NET inherits `ToString()` from the root base class `object`. Extension methods that have the exact same signature as member methods aren't shown and can't be called using the extension methods syntax.